# Fast CSV reading in Common Lisp

Tags: csv, io, common-lisp

What is the fastest way to read a csv file in CL in a way such that:
1) all fields in the first line go into one array called column-names
2) the first field of each of all following lines goes into another
   array called row-names
3) all other fields go into another array called values
?

My file has the following form, just with a lot more columns and rows:

```
"";"ES1 Index";"VG1 Index";"TY1 Comdty";"RX1 Comdty";"GC1 Comdty"
"1999-01-04";1391.12;3034.53;66.515625;86.2;441.39
"1999-01-05";1404.86;3072.41;66.3125;86.17;440.63
"1999-01-06";1435.12;3156.59;66.4375;86.32;441.7
"1999-01-07";1432.32;3106.08;66.25;86.22;447.67
```

And the result I would like is:

```
#("1999-01-04" "1999-01-05" "1999-01-06" "1999-01-07" )
#("" "ES1 Index" "VG1 Index" "TY1 Comdty" "RX1 Comdty" "GC1 Comdty")
#(1391.12 3034.53 66.515625 86.2 441.39 1404.86 3072.41 66.3125 86.17 440.63
  1435.12 3156.59 66.4375 86.32 441.7 1432.32 3106.08 66.25 86.22 447.67)
```

Are you aware of some CL library that does so already?
Are there any general issues regarding I/O performance, maybe compiler-specific, that I should be aware of?

Here is the way I am doing it now:

```
(with-open-file (stream "my-file.csv" :direction :input)
   (let* ((header (read-line stream nil))
          (columns-list (mapcar #'read-from-string
                                (cl-ppcre:split ";" header)))
          (number-of-columns (length columns-list))
          (column-names (make-array number-of-columns
                                    :initial-contents columns-list))
          (rownames (make-array 1 :adjustable t :fill-pointer 0))
          (values (make-array 1 :adjustable t :fill-pointer 0)))
 (set-syntax-from-char #\; #\ )
 (loop
    :for reader = (read stream nil stream)
    :until (eq reader stream)
    :do (progn (vector-push-extend reader row-names)
           (loop
              :for count :from 2 :upto number-of-columns
              :do (vector-push-extend (read stream nil)
                                  values)))
    :finally (return (values row-names
                      column-names
                      values)))))
```

Note: I wouldn't use set-syntax-from-char in real code, I am using it just for the sake of this example.

Comment: The other answers give you the fastest portable way. The fastest non-portable way is to minimise copying (the slowest part). Copying happens when splitting up strings (e.g splitting based on quote marks or on new lines in read-line). If your implementation can be convinced to do it and supports some kind of C FFI that allows you to refer to c-style arrays in some cl object that just stores a pointer and length, then you could just mmap the csv file and parse it in the ram, building up your strings by pointing to the file in memory. This doesn't need copying but won't allow for escaping quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the I/O is the slowest part here.  You can probably get faster I/O if you use [READ-SEQUENCE](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_seq.htm) rather than calling [READ-LINE](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_lin.htm#read-line) repeatedly.  So your code might look something like this:

```
(with-open-file (s "my-file.csv")
  (let* ((len (file-length s))
         (data (make-array len)))
    (read-sequence data s)
     data))
```

Then split `data` by newlines and add your logic.

Whether that helps or not, it'd helpful for you to profile your code, e.g. with `:sb-sprof`, to see where most of the time is being spent.

Answer (score 2):

To read csv files, I find very useful and fast the cl-csv package (https://github.com/AccelerationNet/cl-csv). For instance, to solve your problem, the following code could be used:

```
(let ((data (cl-csv:read-csv #P"my-file.csv" :separator #\;)))
  (values (apply #'vector (first data))
          (apply #'vector (rest (mapcar #'first data)))
          (apply #'vector 
             (mapcar #'read-from-string (loop :for row :in (rest data)
                                              :append (rest row))))))
```

`cl-csv:read-csv` returns a list contaning, for each row, a list of strings that are the contents of the cells.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried it out. Unfortunately, it takes 1.5 times the times the code I wrote takes.  I am looking for performance here.

Comment: What CL implementation you use?

Comment: I am using SBCL, but I am planning to try other implementations too. This actually relates to my question in the post: Are there any general issues regarding I/O performance, maybe compiler-specific, that I should be aware of?

Comment: `APPLY` is not a good idea. See:  `CALL-ARGUMENTS-LIMIT` http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_call_a.htm

Comment: Yes, you are right, I should have used make-array. In my implementation (CCL) `CALL-ARGUMENT-LIMIT` is 65535.

Comment: ABCL says its limit is 50.

Comment: @Alexandre, I have found that file I/O can be very slow in SBCL.